# Allow a SharePoint document to be displayed in a frame

Tags: list, javascript, css, attachments, iframe

I have a SharePoint list with attachment, I want to display these attachment in a Frame for preview but I get this error:

This content cannot be displayed in a frame
To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame.

Apparently its a protection and it's called ClickJacking. Can you tell me how to disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the below solution?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10205192/x-frame-options-allow-from-multiple-domains

You may have to allow that specific domain in which you want to show the documents. You can set `X-Frame-Options` in IIS for the specific site.

Click on the site in IIS. In the middle pane look for `HTTP Response Headers` and add an entry for `X-Frame-Options` with `ALLOW-FROM {your domain}`.